# Username alignment issue in the Stack Apps site

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, display-names, stackapps

There is an alignment issue with the displaying of usernames in the Stack Apps site's [apps](https://stackapps.com/?tab=apps) and [scripts](https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts) tabs. The last characters of the usernames are not being displayed correctly.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Username alignment issue]

After inspecting the element, the alignment issue appears to be at the in-line styling `margin-right : 5px;`. If `margin-right : 5px;` is changed to `margin-right : 8px;` the issue will be solved.

The issue is occurring in Chrome and IE 11 and the same fix solves the problem in both browsers.

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 dev-m
IE Version 11.20.10586.0

Comment: @ShadowWizard : I'm asking out of curiosity, Is it possible to can I pull the repository and push this change as a check-in? Or only Stack Exchange employees can do the changes? Any post related to this?

Comment: I am not a developer, just ordinary user. And not sure what you ask, to be honest. The stackapps site is not open source

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Oh, okay. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Cross-site duplication in [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/q/7279/37357)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently the user name truncation issue has been fixed in the [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/) site, now it is looking good.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Stack Apps]